# playing video with specific height and width in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video

I have a video of framewidth 1280 and frame height 768. If i set my embeded object width and height video gets cut from both the sides. How to play video widthout cutting with specific height and width. video should stretch automatically if i decreases width of my embed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check CONTROLLER, HEIGHT & WIDTH attributes defined in below link, it should be helpful to you.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA26486

Happy coding!!

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried to set following properties but didn't get success. still the same issue.